# Should I put stevia seedlings in direct sunlight or indoor?

Tags: indoors, seeds

This is my first time trying to grow stevia. For my diabetic mother.
I saw videos on the internet. they cover the seedlings with plastic sheets.

The temperature in my area gets from 34 to 24 at night.

Do I need to put the seedlings in direct sunlight all day after covering them with polythene sheet? Or put them indoor till the seeds grow?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't put any seedlings in direct sunlight.  The plastic sheets serve to condense any evaporation and drip down to the seedlings.  They would also maintain heat in a colder climate.

And you really only need one plant, so don't stress if you can't keep all of them alive.

Comment: so, put a sheet on and keep it indoor away from sunlight? is that right?